# Best approach to avoid javascript's "this" mistakes

Tags: javascript, this

In some cases, the `this` keyword may not refer to the object I expect it to. (recent example: [in an key event, in my XBL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499500/calling-a-method-from-xbl/4510486#4510486)

What's the best approach to avoid this kind of mistake?

For now, I'm using always the `$.fn` from jQuery to store my variables, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach.

Comment: The first sentence of your question said it best: `this` is a keyword and *not* a variable

Comment: A good approach I'm using now is always pass a parameter "self" for the functions. It's what Python does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't avoid using *this*. Just use it the right way. Javascript is a prototype based object oriented language. If you create your objects using the object prototype *should* always know what this refers to.

jQuery.fn is the same thing as `jQuery.prototype`. `jQuery.fn` is just an alias. You can also check the this keyword using instanceof.

```
this instanceof jQuery
```

Another common practice is to call a method and bind the context at that time using the `apply` or `call` function methods. This will guarantee the function's *this* context.

Here is a simple example.

```
var div = document.getElementById('div1');
function sayId(){
    alert(this.id);
}
sayId.call(div); // alerts div1
```

The first argument of the call method binds the *this* context and runs the function.

Knowing how to *control* and *check* `this` is the best way to avoid common mistakes.

Comment: I'm wondering, if I have the `div` element, why use `sayId.call(div)` instead of `div.sayId()`?

Comment: sayID is not a method defined on the DOM element. Instead, it is a function declaration defined only in the current variable scope. To apply a specific calling context to a stand-alone function, you have to use the Function.prototype.call or the Function.prototype.apply method.

Answer (score 10):

Learn how and why `this` behaves the way it does, then read the code you're working on.

Don't trust some magic functionality, you might always end up with unexpected results if you don't know/read the code.

There's simply no single awesome solution for this "problem".

Comment: +100 I resent the idea that "this" is a problem and I resent Crockford for persuading so many people not to use it.