# Best approach to avoid javascript's “this” mistakes in XBL

Tags: javascript, binding, xul, this, xbl

Talking about XBL is not exactly talking about javascript. So I'll create this question that's related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520243/best-approach-to-avoid-javascripts-this-mistakes), but now about XBL, where I'm not the creator of the root javascript code, but just of the methods and event handlers inside the bindings.

--

In some cases, the `this` keyword may not refer to the object I expect it to. (recent example: [in an key event, in my XBL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499500/calling-a-method-from-xbl/4510486#4510486)

What's the best approach to avoid this kind of mistake?

For now, I'm using always the `getElementById` (or `$.fn` from jQuery), but I'm not sure if it's the best approach.

**--update**

A little bit more details:

Within a [XBL method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial:Adding_Methods_to_XBL-defined_Elements) the only way to access the element that was defined in the [Xul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL) file (the GUI description file) without using "this" (as it may not be the "this" I expect) is with getElementById, and this makes the code not reusable, so I'm looking for alternatives..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've heard elsewhere, the problem is that the `this` parameter isn't necessarily the object you first thought of, especially when you're talking about event handlers and the like. The best way I found is to write a small function that will bind some object as the `this` variable and return another function that uses the binding to call the original function.

Take a look at this code:

```
var bindFunction = function(self, f) {
  return function() {
    return f.apply(self);
  };
};

var foo = function() {
  alert(this.hello);
};

var bar = { 
  hello: "Hello there"
};

var boundFoo = bindFunction(bar, foo);
boundFoo();
```

What I have is a function called `bindFunction` that takes an object (called `self`) and some function, and returns another function that will call the passed-in function applying the `self` object as the `this` variable.

The rest of the code is just some test code: a `foo` function that will alert `this.hello`, a `bar` object with a `hello` member, and how you can bind `foo` with `bar`.

In essence, I've taken a function that accepts no parameters and generated another function that will ensure the first is always called with the correct `this` variable. Ideal for event handlers.

(Sorry, but I know nothing about XBL, so I hope this will be of use.)

Comment: `bind` is built in EcmaScript 5, and the new `strict` mode makes a lot of `this` problems fail fast.

Comment: Thanks for answering, in your example you have the "bar" to use as "self", but within a [XBL method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial:Adding_Methods_to_XBL-defined_Elements) the only way to access the element that was defined in the [Xul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL) file (the GUI description file) is with getElementById, and this makes the code not reusable, so I'm looking for alternatives..

Comment: Instead of writing otherDoc.addEventListener("event", this.myMethod, false); you now write otherDoc.addEventListener("event", this.bindFunction(this, this.myMethod), false);

Comment: Now, I found out that I can use an approach like `var self = this` and `addEventListener("event", function() { self.myMethod() }, false)`.

Answer (score 0):

If there's not a best answer, a good approach could be use javascript files instead of XBL for the implementation. Looking the Xulrunner source code, looks like most code does this.

But I still would like to use XBL, if there was a way to work fine with it..